# Import CSV Error Exception: Cannot convert ',' to char

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a script based off [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57221421/how-to-use-google-apps-script-to-copy-data-from-gmail-attachment-to-sheets) which takes a CSV attachment from Gmail and then pastes it into a Google Sheet, and when I try use the script again on a new sheet it gives me an error:

> Exception: Cannot convert ',' to char. (line 22, file "Code")

Line of code:

> ```
>   var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ',');
> ```

The thing I find really weird I have the exact same line of code in other scripts and they work without issue. I've even tried copy/pasting the line of code from the working scripts.

```js
function importCSVFromGmail() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search("redacted");
  var message = threads[0].getMessages().pop();

  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

  if (attachment != null) {
    var attachName = attachment.getName();

    // Is the attachment a CSV file
    if (attachName.substring(attachName.length-4) === ".csv") {
      var id = "redacted";
      var name = "Data Sheet";
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
      var tab = sheet.getSheetByName(name);
      

      // Clear the content of the sheet
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");
      tab.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
    }
  } 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I can't figure out why I'm getting the error only in new scripts.

Comment: Would it be possible to share a redacted version of the csv file that you're trying to parse?

Comment: Try `var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString())`

Comment: Hello Mo4735! Did @TheMaster's suggestion work for you? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as @TheMaster suggested, you should change your line of code from this

`var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");`

to this

`var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString());`

You can also read more about the `.parseCsv()` function [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think removing the parameter is the best solution.

Here is the definition from Google:
parseCsv(csv, delimiter)

Here is my solution:

```
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ','.charCodeAt(0));
```

Note: Removing the parameter in your example may have no difference as ',' is the default delimiter in this function. It may make a lot more sense on a situation that you need another delimiter like ';'